# Concat arrays of grouped lines

Tags: python, arrays, concatenation, grouping

I have the following array:

```
[
  ["String 0", [1, 2]],
  ["String 1", [1, 3]],
  ["String 2", []],
  ["String 3", [2]],
  ["String 1", [1, 2]],
  ["String 2", [0]]
]
```

I need to transform it into an array with unique Strings (first column) and concatenated second column.

Here is what output should look like:

```
[
  ["String 0", [1, 2]],
  ["String 1", [1, 3, 1, 2]],
  ["String 2", [0]],
  ["String 3", [2]]
]
```

In this case, Strings are unique and `"String 1"` has a second column `"1, 3, 1, 2"` and `"String 2"` has second column `"0"`.

I know how to unique an array but not how to group and concatenate at the same time.

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary?

Comment: How is the array created in the first place? I think that might be the place to solve the problem.

Comment: looks like better to make a dict

Answer (score 1):

Like the IanAuld suggests, a dictionary is likely the best way to handle this.

Try the following

```
arr_of_arrs = [
    ["String 0", [1, 2]],
    ["String 1", [1, 3]],
    ["String 2", []],
    ["String 3", [2]],
    ["String 1", [1, 2]],
    ["String 2", [0]]
  ]
from collections import defaultdict
arrs = defaultdict(lambda: [])
for arr in arr_of_arrs:
    arrs[arr[0]] += arr[1]
```

How to convert the dictionary back to your array of arrays is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

This will match your required output:

```
l = [
    ["String 0", [1, 2]],
    ["String 1", [1, 3]],
    ["String 2", []],
    ["String 3", [2]],
    ["String 1", [1, 2]],
    ["String 2", [0]]
    ]
unique = {x[0] for x in l}
new_arr = [[x,[]] for x in unique]
for k in l:
    for n in new_arr:
        if k[0] == n[0]:
            n[1] += k[1]

In [5]: new_arr                   
Out[5]: 
[['String 3', [2]],
 ['String 2', [0]],
 ['String 1', [1, 3, 1, 2]],
 ['String 0', [1, 2]]]
```